# Column cannot be null SPRING BOOT @OneToMany and @ManyToOne

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, relationship

My "invoice" table is related to "invoice_detail", when I want to save the complete invoice object, with its list of details, it throws me the error: "invoice_id" cannot be null (This in the invoice_detail table).

My tables: (MySQL)

```
create table factura
(
    id             int auto_increment
        primary key,
    cantidad_items int          null,
    codigo         varchar(255) null,
    costo_total    int          null,
    fecha          datetime     null
);

create table factura_detalle
(
    id              int auto_increment
        primary key,
    cantidad        int          null,
    id_factura      int          not null,
    item            varchar(255) null,
    precio_unitario int          null,
    foreign key (id_factura) references factura(id)
)
```

My Entity:

```
@Entity @Getter @Setter
@Table(name = "factura")
public class Factura {

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = FacturaDetalle.class, mappedBy = "factura", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<FacturaDetalle> facturaDetalles;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "codigo")
    private String codigo;

    @Column(name = "cantidad_items")
    private Integer cantidadItems;

    @Column(name = "costo_total")
    private Integer costoTotal;

    @Column(name = "fecha")
    private Date fecha;

}

@Entity @Getter @Setter
@Table(name = "factura_detalle")
public class FacturaDetalle {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_factura", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Factura factura;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "cantidad")
    private Integer cantidad;

    @Column(name = "precio_unitario")
    private Integer precioUnitario;

    @Column(name = "id_factura")
    private Integer idFactura;

    @Column(name = "item")
    private String item;

}
```

My Object before to save:
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHVDc.png)

Finally, my error is the following:

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: **Column 'id_factura' cannot be null**
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]

Comment: Well your db table has constraint to have not null on column id_factura. You need to supply a value to this field/column.

Answer (score 0):

I think your relationship of entities are not right. Please check the entity relationship.

You don't need to add below extra column  because bi-directional will create the foreign key in child side. Here FacturaDetail is a child of Factura.

```
@Column(name = "id_factura")
    private Integer idFactura;
```

please try... it should work.

```
 package com.example.stackoverflowanswers.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "factura")
public class Factura {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Integer id;

   @Column(name = "codigo")
   private String codigo;

   @Column(name = "cantidad_items")
   private Integer cantidadItems;

   @Column(name = "costo_total")
   private Integer costoTotal;

   @Column(name = "fecha")
   private Date fecha;

   @OneToMany(
           mappedBy = "factura",
           cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
           orphanRemoval = true
   )
   private List<FacturaDetalle> facturaDetalles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
   package com.example.stackoverflowanswers.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "factura_detalle")
public class FacturaDetalle {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "cantidad")
    private Integer cantidad;

    @Column(name = "precio_unitario")
    private Integer precioUnitario;

    @Column(name = "item")
    private String item;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_factura")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Factura factura;
}
```